# SSIS - Only Export Column Based on Result

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS in order to create a csv file based on TSQL code.

One of the issues I am having is that the csv file should only create a particular column, if that particular piece of data exists in the TSQL code.

Example, I am exporting a list of properties. Those properties could have a number of adaptations.

Using one of the many adaptations that a property can have -  one is Stair Lift. So in my TSQL SELECT statement, I will have a column that simply is a true or false result.

If it is true then on the CSV column I would expect the corresponding Stair Lift column to be exported.

If it was false, then I wouldn't want the column of Stair Lift to be on the export at all.

I'm stumped how to achieve that in SSIS  - any advice would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically SSIS requires columns and mappings to be defined at design time and can't be changed. You're going to have to use some kind of coding to so this. Here's some powershell that might do what you want: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2004085-export-sql-server-query-result-to-csv-using-powershell-script

Comment: ..and this https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SQL-query-dump-to-CSV-5b0f4b46

Comment: Can you concatonate the SQL result into a single column that will load the CSV file?  That would allow for variable results

Answer (score 0):

Best approach could be , go for a script component and write conditional statements in C# and create the CSV with the desired list of columns.

```
For Each row As DataRow In _BufferTable.Rows
    Output0Buffer.AddRow()
    If row.IsNull("Column1") Then
        Output0Buffer.Column1_IsNull = True
    Else
        Output0Buffer.Column1 = CType(row.Item("Column1"), Double)
    End If
Next
```

Else , using conditional split and dynamically deriving column names are painful.

Comment: I'll have to stay clear of C# - have no skills in that whatsoever.